# Error ERR-7620 Could not determine workspace for application (4500)

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I try to lunch Oracle APEX by this link: http://127.0.0.1:8081/apex/apex

8081 is the port that I choose.

this error is occured:
    Error   ERR-7620 Could not determine workspace for application (4500).
ORA-01403: no data found

Anyone has an idea about thie problem

Comment: have a look at this, this talks about upgrade, but even in fresh installation it should help https://community.oracle.com/thread/3701446?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Look like you have too many occurrences of apex in the link try http://127.0.0.1:8081/apex

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your URL syntax is incorrect. Should look something like this http://"insertyourdomainorIP"/apex/f?p="applicationid" etc....
here is a great link to help understand http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2015/01/understanding-apex-url-passing.html